# Unable to read output from System Command executed in R

Tags: r

I am new to R. So please bear with me if the question seems to be simple to you.

I was trying to execute a java program from R.

```
randomGraphPoints<-function(exec="randomcoordinates")
    {
      command=paste("java -cp . ",exec)
      system(command)
    }
```

The above function `randomGraphPoints` when executed shows an output as shown below:

```
> source("Hello.R")
> randomGraphPoints()
(-12,7,-6,-7,10,-6,5,-8,-4,2,10,-12,-4,-13,-1,-15,12,12,1,8,-11,-13,-6,-3,6,-3,1,12,10,10,-8,15,-15,6,1,4,-13,-8,-6,2)
```

My plan is to create a matrix which consists of 2 columns. The output should be like:

```
-12,7
-6,-7
10,-6
5,-8
-4,2
10,-12
....
-6,2
```

and then plot a graph using Graphviz.

I am stuck at the stage where I need to assign the output from System call in R to a R Variable.

Please advice me on how to proceed.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `intern = TRUE` to get proper R output from `system()`.  Then you can safely assign the reault.  So try changing last line of the function to

```
system(command, intern = TRUE)
```

So then the function would be

```
randomGraphPoints <- function(exec = "randomcoordinates") {
    command = paste("java -cp . ", exec)
    system(command, intern = TRUE)
}
```

And then you can do

```
x <- randomGraphPoints()
matrix(scan(text = x, sep = ","), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: HI Richard, The code works fine now. But I have a problem. The output is   `matrix(x, 2, byrow = TRUE)
     [,1]                                                                                                                
[1,] "12,-10,8,3,14,-1,14,3,-14,0,-7,-12,14,-3,3,-5,-15,-14,14,-11,-5,2,-15,15,4,0,0,-5,-3,-13,0,8,5,4,-10,5,-5,-1,-4,13"
[2,] "12,-10,8,3,14,-1,14,3,-14,0,-7,-12,14,-3,3,-5,-15,-14,14,-11,-5,2,-15,15,4,0,0,-5,-3,-13,0,8,5,4,-10,5,-5,-1,-4,13"` The matrix is not getting formed. Instead it is showing two rows of the whole output obtained above

Comment: @Dev - Sorry, please see my updated post.  That should do it

Comment: Wow ! Thanks a lot @Richard ! Works like a charm !

Comment: @Dev - Happy to help.  You can accept this (or any) answer by clicking the grey check-mark.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: Done ! Just a quick question - Is Graphviz a stable option to plot a graph? If yes, any idea how to plot the graph from the matrix obtained above.

Comment: I have never used Graphvis before, but you can obtain a simple scatter plot with `m <- matrix(scan(text = x, sep = ","), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE); plot(m)` and play around with the arguments to make it look a little nicer.  See `help(plot)` for a list of all the available arguments. Also, many people use the package `ggplot2` for plotting

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for the inputs @Richard. Will work on it.